# R plto_ly or ggplot: fade in line with changing opacity

Tags: r, plotly, opacity

In an plot_ly plot I want a line to fade in using the opacity parameter. I thought I group the data into as many groups as there are datapoints and add an opacity parameter. However the groups do not get connected so there is nothing plotted.

```
library(plotly)
xg = as.character(c(1:100))  
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,xg = as.factor(xg), y = 1:100, opacity =0.01*(1:100))

df <-group_by(df, xg)
plot_ly(df)%>%
add_trace( x =~x, y= ~y, opacity = ~opacity )
```

And it doesent even work with markers, the opacity is constant:

```
library(plotly)
xg = as.character(c(1:100))  
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,xg = as.factor(xg), y = 1:100, opacity =0.01*(1:100))

df <-group_by(df, xg)
plot_ly(df)%>%
add_markers( x =~x, y= ~y, opacity = ~opacity )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, but correct me if I'm wrong. Here I'll make the plot in ggplot, then covert to plotly.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x =x, y = y,alpha = opacity))+
    geom_point()+
    theme_classic()

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

I think what you're looking for to "fade" the line is the alpha argument.

Comment: Awesome, especially because it also works for `geom_line()`! Thank you.

Comment: @PascalIv Doesn't work directly for me with `geom_line()`, did you have to change something else in the plot definition?

Comment: For a line, just do not convert to plotly. It works without modification in ggplot